# Need a Regex to identify the string "hostname abc_pqr_xyz" (The 3 words can be any thing)

Tags: regex

I would like to check all the strings with the format `hostname abc_pqr_xyz` in a file. Need a regex for this. There should be exactly 2 _'s and 3 words in the string.

I have tried using  the regex `^hostname \s+.*_.*_.*`

But it is giving a positive result for `abc_abc_abc_abc_abc`, as it considering `abc_abc_abc` as one word.

Comment: Use `^hostname\s+[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$`

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `[^_]` negated character class that matches any char but `_` instead of `.`:

```
^hostname\s+[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F014o5/1/) and a [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Ehostname%5Cs%2B%5B%5E_%5D*_%5B%5E_%5D*_%5B%5E_%5D*%24):

[image]

See `$` at the end that checks the end of the string.

Also, a space before `\s+` will require a space and then 1 or more whitespace chars, thus, that space may be harmful, that's why I removed it from the expression.

Note you may group the `_[^_]*` and then set the number of repetitions that you may adjust in the future:

```
^hostname\s+[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){2}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F014o5/2).